# Attempting to Read Certain Values from a File into an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I have a file,examplefile.txt, with data like this:

```
0.000 3.142
3.142 4.712
4.712 1.571
```

I am trying to read only the values in the second column. In an effort to do this I have been using the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double tempvalue;
    int a,b;

    FILE *file;
    char *myfile=malloc(sizeof(char)*80);
    sprintf(myfile,"examplefile.txt");
    if (fopen(myfile,"r")==NULL)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        file=fopen(myfile,"r");
        for (a=0;a<3;a++)
        {
            for (b=0;b<2;b++)
            {
                printf("a=%d\n",a);
                fscanf(file,"%lf",&tempvalue);
                if (b==1)
                {
                    printf("%lf\n",tempvalue);
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

However,this only returns the value 1.571 every time. I can't store all of the values because the actual file I'm using contains too many values to store. I have not been able to find a solution for this problem yet.

Comment: 6 values is too many? Are you writing one on each of your fingers? Of one hand?

Comment: No it isn't. My actual file contains 100,000,000 values in two columns of 50,000,000 values apiece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading both, and just ignoring the first. Something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float v1, v2;
    FILE* file = fopen(myfile, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("open failed");
        return -1;
        }
    while(fscanf(file, "%f %f", &v1, &v2) == 2) {
        print("read %f\n", v2);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `while(fscanf(file, "%f %f", &v1, &v2) == 2)` would ensure you read two values successfully.